# How to get column name from gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I would like to know how can I get a column name from a gridview? by its number not by name.
like : Name|Age|Birthday: ( so name=0 , age=1 etc...)

thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get it like this :

```
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text
```

Or like this :

```
gv.Rows[0].Cells[i].Text
```

Rows[0] should be your header row.

Comment: 37 minutes later, and no answer marked.  Maybe the notification of this will remind them.

Comment: hi I've tried and I only get the number , I need to get the column name

Comment: I get &nbsp; instead of the name of column

Comment: Did you even set a header text? Or is you header text &nbsp;...?

Comment: the column name? is .. called Name , I should get name?

Comment: Let me see how you do this, show some code so I can help you!

Comment: thank you , this is my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607032/on-gridview-updated-get-all-modified-cells-in-a-textbox-non-edited

Comment: I want to see how you set your column name

Comment: my column name is declared in the database , new table -> and wrote some names from columns.

Answer (score 3):

```
//// Header column names
int gridViewCellCount = yourGridView.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
// string array to hold grid view column names.
string[] columnNames = new string[gridViewCellCount];

for (int i = 0; i < gridViewCellCount; i++)
{
    columnNames[i] = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell)(yourGridView.Rows[0].Cells[i])).ContainingField.HeaderText;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

simply

```
 GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;
```

try this if you want to all the cells value from each of the rows

```
  foreach (GridViewRow r in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        string s = r.Cells[0].Text;
        string y = r.Cells[1].Text;
    }
```

**update:**

try this

```
  foreach (TableCell Tc in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
    {
        //if you are not getting value than find childcontrol of TabelCell.
        string sssb = Tc.Text;
        foreach (Control ctl in Tc.Controls)
        {

            //Child controls
            Label lb = ctl as Label;
            string s = lb.Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi I've tried and I only get the number , I need to get the column name

Comment: may be your column cell in the childcontrol on HeaderRow.try my update code.and let me know what happen?

Comment: I get object reference not set to an instance of an object string s= lb.text

Comment: strange!! its work in my page. can you see in console what is your cells be render in HTML page?

Comment: I can see all the gridview with all the information fi that's what you mean

Comment: ask to u that when your gridview render in browser that time using console see headerrow's cell. Append in Span tag?

Comment: I really don't know what do you mean , but I can see the columns and the cells everything is fine

Answer (score 1):

Revisiting this old question.... it's possible to get the field names of the data bound to a GridView with this kind of code.  This makes a dictionary of colnum and field name.

```
private static IDictionary<int, string> GetGridViewFieldNames(object grid)
{
    var names = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    var view = grid as GridView;
    if (view != null)  {
        for (var i = 0; i < view.Columns.Count; i++)  {
            var field = view.Columns[i] as BoundField;
            if (field != null)  {
                names.Add(i, field.DataField);
            }
        }
    }
    return names;
}
```

Comment: Only answer here that takes a stab at field name instead of column label text.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer to the question.  It is only the answer if you never change the header text in the gridview.  The asker of the question wanted to get the database field name by index.

I've seen a number of "answers" which only provide the text in the selected row of a gridview, or the header text which both do not answer the question that was asked...

You may ask why?  If you were going to do audits of updates in a system and wanted to compare old values and new values and only update if they change and want to indicate which field was updated how do you show the **database table field name** at the index of the loop.

For instance:

```
Protected Sub gv_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Dim intValCount As Integer = Integer.Parse(e.NewValues.Count)
    If intValCount > 0 Then
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For i = 0 To intValCount - 1
            If Not e.OldValues(i).Equals(e.NewValues(i)) Then
                ' values have changed, audit the change
                Sys.Audits.General(intID, "the_database_table", <the table field by index(i)>, e.OldValues(i).ToString, e.NewValues(i).ToString)
            End If
            i += 1
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

So the questions is how do you get the database table field name by index via code behind?  I too have been searching for this and all the "answers" that I've seen are not the answers I think some of us are really looking for.  All the mentioned methods I've seen here are not bullet proof references to a database tables field name.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy: Here i read the gridview header text for each header cell and add them as new columns to a data table.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach(DataControlFieldHeaderCell column in yourGridview.HeaderRow.Cells)
{
  dt.Columns.Add(column.Text.Trim().Replace(" ", ""));                           
}

//Make sure you do all this after yourGridview.DataBind(); 
//If you do not want to bind data first simply bind an empty list like so:
/* yourGridview.DataSource = new List<string>();
   yourGridview.DataBind(); */
```