# On gridview updated get all modified cells in a textbox + non edited?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm trying to add in a textbox all values modified in cells + the others who aren't edited:

```
table name : info
columns : Name|Subname|Age|Birthday|Code
```

I'm using on grid view update

```
for(int i =0;i<4;i++){
if(e.OldValues[i].ToString() != e.NewValues[i].ToString())
{
Textbox1.text = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text + " " + e.OldValues[i].ToString() + " edited with " + e.NewValues[i].ToString();
}
```

1. It's not working I'm getting information just from 1 edited cell , if I edit 2 cells from a row I get random cell information , I mean If I edit `Name` and `Sub Name` I get Name old value and new value istead of getting both.
2. I want to add + the other values who aren't edited.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are not "adding" to the textbox, you are overwriting it with "="

```
Textbox1.text = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text + " " + e.OldValues[i].ToString() + " edited with " + e.NewValues[i].ToString();
```

Try this:

```
Textbox1.text += GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text + " " + e.OldValues[i].ToString() + " edited with " + e.NewValues[i].ToString();
```

Changed the "=" for "+=".

And for the non edited values, something like? :

```
    if(e.OldValues[i].ToString() != e.NewValues[i].ToString())
    {
        Textbox1.text += GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text + " " + e.OldValues[i].ToString() + " edited with " + e.NewValues[i].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        Textbox2.text += GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text + " " + e.OldValues[i].ToString() + " didn't change";
    }
```

Comment: By the way, I noticed you've never marked any post as ANSWER. When you get an answer that works, plz mark it as answer!

Comment: huh you're right lol forgot the += ! but how can I add the non edited values? and ok I'll mark sorry I'm new

Comment: You should check your previous questions too, none are marked as answered... To mark as answer, you have to click the "check" button on the top left corner of an answer...

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ to get the necessary informations:

```
var changed = e.NewValues.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
    .Where(entry => entry.Value != e.OldValues[entry.Key])
    .Select(entry => String.Format("{0} was edited with {1}",entry.Key,entry.Value));
var notChanged = e.NewValues.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
    .Where(entry  => entry.Value == e.OldValues[entry.Key])
    .Select(entry => String.Format("{0} was not changed",entry.Key));

TxtChanged.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, changed);
TxtUnchanged.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, notChanged);
```

Comment: Would you please tell me what namespace should I use becase .where is not recognized and entry too .

Comment: @InziIrina: At least these:  `System.Linq` and `System.Collections`

Comment: Would you please answer to my initial code? I really appreciate your answers but my code looks familiar to me and I can understand it , everything works perfect now but I need to kno how can I add the non edited values?

Comment: @InziIrina: I your code works, why don't you simply iterate all values again to check if `e.OldValues[i].ToString() == e.NewValues[i].ToString()`?