# How to dynamically retrieve the column index, id and the row index of a row in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a dynamically created grdview with `4` columns and `n` number of rows.
Each column has a `Button` control with different `Id`s. The control has a `Click` event. When the event fires I want to find the `row` index and the `cell` index or the `Id` of that button at the run time

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method to Find GridView Column Index by Name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925183/method-to-find-gridview-column-index-by-name)

Comment: I even have to find the name too @whereisSQL

Comment: Can I know how to find the name using codebehind @whereisSQL

Comment: I just did a search in the search box to find that link. :) Here is 1 I found for the column name http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606720/how-to-get-column-name-from-gridview

Comment: I have to get that dynamically when the button clicks, how can I give `i`, It has to be dynamic @whereisSQL

Answer (score 0):

In this article  will explain how to get the ASP.Net GridView Row and its RowIndex client side using JavaScript. I will also explain how we can find the GridView Cells and the controls inside the GridView Template Fields client side using JavaScript.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function GetSelectedRow(lnk) {
            var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;
            var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
            var customerId = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
            var city = row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
            alert("RowIndex: " + rowIndex + " CustomerId: " + customerId + " City:" + city);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" AllowPaging = "true" OnPageIndexChanging = "PageIndexChanging">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField = "CustomerID" HeaderText = "CustomerID" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "City">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Text = '<%# Eval("City") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName = "Select" OnClientClick = "return GetSelectedRow(this)" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should probably include the [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Get-ASPNet-GridView-Row-and-its-RowIndex-when-clicked-using-JavaScript.aspx) of where you grabbed the code snippet from.

Comment: o i forget that sorry mate...but i coppied it form somewhere

Comment: I have few other things to do on server side, so I want to do it on server side on cs page @KeefeHiggins

Comment: do want to find the control inside cells and and id of row clicked ?

Comment: Yeah on the server code in code behind file @AsifAhmad

Answer (score 0):

to find the Index of row u can simply do this

```
GridViewRow gvr = e.Row;
```

or

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
```

and to find the value of the control for example  text of the text box u can do this

```
Label lb_ID = (TextBox)GridInvoice.Rows[index].Cells[1].FindControl("Label_ID");
```

where index is row index and cell[1] is cell index i.e  if u have 4 cells in your grid then index starts from cell[0]... cell[3]. Here cell[1] means control is in cell 2 of ur grid .
if u have grid values binding form database and you have some unique id like primary key coming also and u are performing opreration on this value in database then From Frond end add this property to gridview ( DatakeyNames="ur primary key or uniqe value comming form database "; and now if u have button or link button control ( or any other control which raises event in grid view then on the event write this code which will automatically capture primary key and row index for u.

```
   protected void lnkbtnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gvrows = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
      int32  Key = (Convert.ToInt32(grvCityList.DataKeys[gvrows.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString()));

Now do ur logic here 

    }
```

hope u will get what u are look for

Comment: I'm getting an exception : FormatException. Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: The fact is that I even have to get the cell index at run time. I have get that runtime @Asif Ahmad

Comment: try to change the Int32 to ur format i.e what kind of format

Comment: I have changed it, its nothing about that

Comment: debug n check in which line exception is raised n let me knw

Comment: RowIndex is being `zero`. ON 2nd line

Comment: int32 index = convert.toInt32(e.rowindex);

Comment: `e` doesn't have a property `rowindex`

Comment: did u try the 2nd way ?