# How to get column name and create string variable dynamically?

Tags: c#, gridview

Through Edit link button I'm able to edit record using code below . As you can see here number of columns are 4 , for fixed column number this code is fine but In my condition Column numbers are not fixed ,they may 4 or may be 5 for next insert. How can I get column names and create that number of string variable, so that I can assign string values to particular field ?

[image]

```
  protected void OnUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

    string a = (row.Cells[3].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
    string b = (row.Cells[4].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
    string c = (row.Cells[5].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
    string d = (row.Cells[6].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;

    DataTable dt = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;

    dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["Column0"] = a;
    dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["Column1"] = b;
    dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["Column2"] = c;
    dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["Column3"] = d;

    ViewState["dt"] = dt;
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    this.BindGrid();
    btnGetSelected.Visible = true;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
 protected void OnUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    DataTable dt = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;
    int j=0;
    for (int i = 3; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
          string a = (row.Cells[i].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
          dt.Rows[row.RowIndex][j] = a;
          j++;
    }
    ViewState["dt"] = dt;
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    this.BindGrid();
    btnGetSelected.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: If a posted answer helped you to find this solution, you should mark it as the correct answer, and post the working solution as an edit inside your post rather than as an answer. Just an advice. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you need the columns names of the `GridView`?

You could use either of these

```
gv.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text

gv.Rows[0].Cells[i].Text
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606720/how-to-get-column-name-from-gridview)

It you want column names of `DataTable` use

```
string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                 .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                                 .ToArray();
```